# Related lat,lng using javascript

Tags: laravel

```html
<script>                                                                                

    /* Edit */                                                                                
    function initialize() 
    {                  

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.165691,10.451526000000058);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {                                                                             
    center: latlng,                                                                             
    zoom: 13                                                                                
    });     


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                                                                               
    map: map,                                                                               
    position: latlng,                                                                               
    draggable: true,                                                                                

    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)                                                                              
    });                                                                             
    var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');

    // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);                                                                             
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();                                                                                
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);                                                                              
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);                                                                             
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();                                                                              
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {                                                                              
    infowindow.close();                                                                             
    marker.setVisible(false);                                                                               
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();                                                                                
    if (!place.geometry) {                                                                              
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");                                                                             
    return;                                                                             
    }                                                                               

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.                                                                               
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {                                                                              
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);                                                                             
    } else {                                                                                
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);                                                                             
    map.setZoom(17);                                                                                
    }                                                                               

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);                                                                                
    marker.setVisible(true);                                                                                
       alert('Edit=' +place.formatted_address);                                                                              
    bindDataToForm(place.formatted_address,place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());                                                                                
    infowindow.setContent(place.formatted_address);                                                                             
    infowindow.open(map, marker);                                                                               

    });                                                                             
    // this function will work on marker move event into map                                                                                
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {                                                                               
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {                                                                              
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                                                                              
    if (results[0]) {                                                                               
    bindDataToForm(results[0].formatted_address,marker.getPosition().lat(),marker.getPosition().lng());                                                                             
    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);                                                                                
    infowindow.open(map, marker);                                                                               
    }                                                                               
    }                                                                               
    });                                                                             
    });                                                                             
    }                                                                               
    function bindDataToForm(address,lat,lng){                                                                               
    document.getElementById('location').value = address;                                                                                
    document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;                                                                             
    document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
    alert('Edit'+lng);                                                                             
    }                                                                               
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);                                                                                                                   
    </script> 


<script>
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify what you're asking? There's no question here, just code

Comment: Also this looks like JavaScript code but your only tag is Laravel, that is probably not right

Comment: When I update GeoLocation In bootstrap popup form modal Only in first record  get lat ,lng behalf of address and location show on map .first record  update is working fine,When I update second record unable to get lat ,lng behalf of address ,and unable to show map

Comment: Hi Rambabu.

Please update your question with some context. Maybe put what you are commenting into the question instead ?

Comment: I working on Manage Restaurant admin Panel Add Restaurant form and Edit retaurant Form is opening in bootstrap pop up modal .When I  add two Reaturant  from admin panel type address and get lat,lng  and show address on map using javascript api key get location and save into database,every thing is working fine,but When I update first Restaurant every thing is getting from  restaurant table behalf of Id ....

Comment: but When I update first Restaurant every thing is getting from  restaurant table behalf of Id .
If I want to update second record every thing is getting from database behalf of id, but map and location auto suggestion  not working when I want to change location .I getting address lat,lng mention javascript code same as copy the code and change map id and search input text id to add Reastaunt with location